# How to implement linear interpolation in python?

Tags: python

I want to implement a function interpolate(x, y, X_new) that computes the linear interpolation of the unknown function f at a new point x_new. The sample is given in the form of two sequences x and y. Both sequences have the same length, and their elements are numbers. The x sequence contains the points where the function has been sampled, and the y sequence contains the function value at the corresponding point. (without using import statement).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you want to write some function `y = interpolate(x_values, y_values, x)`, which will give you the `y` value at some `x`? The basic idea then follows these steps:

1. Find the indices of the values in `x_values` which define an interval containing `x`. For instance, for `x=3` with your example lists, the containing interval would be `[x1,x2]=[2.5,3.4]`, and the indices would be `i1=1`, `i2=2`
2. Calculate the slope on this interval by `(y_values[i2]-y_values[i1])/(x_values[i2]-x_values[i1])` (ie `dy/dx`).
3. The value at `x` is now the value at `x1` plus the slope multiplied by the distance from `x1`.

You will additionally need to decide what happens if `x` is outside the interval of `x_values`, either it's an error, or you could interpolate "backwards", assuming the slope is the same as the first/last interval.

Did this help, or did you need more specific advice?